# Function that is guaranteed to be one-way if one-way functions exist?

Tags: universal-computation, one-way-function

There is an old trick for writing down an algorithm that, if P = NP, solves SAT in polynomial time.  Essentially, one lists all polynomial time machines and multi-tasks over them.

Is there an analogous trick for one-way functions (or even one-way trapdoor functions)?  That is, can we write down a function that, if one-way functions exist, is necessarily a one-way function?

There seems to be no easy way to mimic the P = NP trick.  In that case, we can quickly recognize a solution when we get one.  But if I multi-task over all polynomial time functions, there's no obvious way to recognize a one-way function when I arrive at one.

If the answer to the above question is no, is there some kind of argument why we can't do it?  Maybe writing down such a function would somehow prove that one-way functions exist?

Comment: Hi Timothy Chow, maybe you can help and point to a link where the trick for writing down an algorithm, that if P = NP, solves SAT in polynomial time, is formalized? Thanks allot

Comment: @AviTal See for example this: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Universal_search

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, such a function was found by Levin himself, published somewhat recently:

[The tale of one-way functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0012023). Problems of Information Transmission (= Problemy Peredachi Informatsii), 39(1):92-103, 2003.

Comment: Thanks! Using Google Scholar, I was able to use this reference to find a reference for a complete public key cryptosystem, by Grigoriev, Hirsch, and Pervyshev, Groups-Complexity-Cryptology 1 (2009), 1-12.

Comment: Could you please explain details of this function? As why it aborts after n^2 steps, why to 'preserve a copy of the program prefix and force it, as well as
the input length, on the output' and what 'only
at places where such possible extension is unique' means exactly. I don't know if this deserves a separate question.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/44496/describe-levins-tile-expansion-one-way-functon-in-layman-terms