# Describe Levins 'Tile Expansion' one way functon in layman terms

Tags: one-way-function

I'd like some explanation on the details of the 'Complete OWF' presented on this paper in 'layman terms'.

See page 13 of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0012023.pdf

I'd prefer that the answerer had 'initiative'. That is - the answer should cover all aspects that could be described without jargon, or to give the definition of those terms in layman terms, without me having to list all those aspects. Thats because, in order to properly explain my doubts, I'd have to explain my 'guesses' on all those items and why they seem not to be correct, and the question would be too long. Also, other users may have different doubts, and sticking to mine may make this question less useful to the community (I expect moderators intervene if this doesn't seem adequate).